# Insert ArrayList into While-condition?

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, equals

I have a program where the user will have the opportunity to choose from multiple strings in order to proceed:

```
System.out.println("\n\tWelcome! Please choose a song!");
        String songChoice = scan.nextLine();
```

A While-loop is following this code, catching all the inputs that aren't matching the conditions.

```
while(!songChoice.equals("Stay") || (!songChoice.equals("Hello")) || (!songChoice.equals("Solitude"))
```

And so on.

I have about fifteen different songs to choose from, and I'm wondering if it's possible to insert an ArrayList in the while-condition instead of writing 15 different conditions for each and one of the strings? Something like...

```
while(!songChoice.equals(songs)
```

I've tried around but I can't get it to work... hope someone out there can help me with this!

Comment: Instead of arraylist you should use a [`set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (HashSet is probably a reasonable choice) and check if the `set.contains(songChoice)`

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the guidelines for a minimum runnable code snippet. Your scanner variable (scan) is not declared and that makes us have assumptions about the way the code works.

A possible solution is to create an ArrayList, populate it with all the strings and check if the input matches one of those strings.

```
List<String> songList = new ArrayList<>();
songList.add("Some song"); //Repeat until satisfied

System.out.println("\n\tWelcome! Please choose a song!");
String songChoice = scan.nextLine();
while (!songList.contains(songChoice)) {
    //Do stuff when input is not a recognised song
}
```

I heavily recommend checking the javadocs of ArrayList (or any class you struggle with) for any suitable methods/fields. You already found ArrayList, why did you not understand what it does and how to use it?

Comment: Thank you!! After I switched "equals" to "contains", the code worked! I will keep on checking out javadocs to learn more :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ArrayList` to store songs :

```
ArrayList<String> availableSongs = Arrays.asList("Hello", "Stay", "Solitude", "Gratitude");

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("\n\tWelcome! Please choose a song!");
boolean validSongChoosen;

while(!validSongChoosen) {
     String songChoice = scan.nextLine();
     if(availableSongs.contains(songChoice)) {
         validSongChoosen = true;
     } else {
         System.out.println("\n\tThe song you have choosen is not available");
     }
}
```

**Small improvement**

Instead of using `ArrayList` you can use a `Set` as others also advised. A Set have the particularity to contains only unique non repetitive elements.

This is the cas for your songs. You can't normally have two songs with same name!

So just change your `ArrayList` with a `HashSet`

Comment: Ohhh, great! Thank you! It works now! Haha, I like the song-add you did!

Comment: Glad, it helped. Keep going!

Comment: Having a +1 or even an accepted answer would be great :)